# JSON.net deserialization returns a null object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to extend the HelpScoutNet project so I can take advantage of reports. I'm having one hell of a time getting the JSON I get from HelpScout to deserialize into my classes. Hopefully you guys can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

JSON according to the API documents:

```
 {
  "filterTags": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "sample-tag"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "user": {
    "id": 4,
    "hasPhoto": true,
    "createdAt": "2010-09-03T15:55:48Z",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "totalCustomersHelped": 6580,
    "photoUrl": "http://example.com/pic.jpg"
  },
  "current": {
    "startDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "endDate": "2015-01-31T23:59:59Z",
    "totalDays": 30,
    "resolved": 1,
    "conversationsCreated": 15,
    "closed": 3,
    "totalReplies": 58,
    "resolvedOnFirstReply": 0,
    "percentResolvedOnFirstReply": 0.0,
    "repliesToResolve": 2.0,
    "handleTime": 78.96,
    "happinessScore": 66.66666666666666,
    "responseTime": 2278004,
    "resolutionTime": 2278004.0,
    "repliesPerDay": 1.9333333333333333,
    "customersHelped": 26,
    "totalConversations": 19,
    "conversationsPerDay": 0.6333333333333333,
    "busiestDay": 5
  },
  "previous": {
    "startDate": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "endDate": "2014-01-31T23:59:59Z",
    "totalDays": 30,
    "resolved": 12,
    "conversationsCreated": 2,
    "closed": 33,
    "totalReplies": 40,
    "resolvedOnFirstReply": 4,
    "percentResolvedOnFirstReply": 0.3333333333333333,
    "repliesToResolve": 2.1666666666666665,
    "handleTime": 0.0,
    "happinessScore": 23.529411764705884,
    "responseTime": 2357169,
    "resolutionTime": 4318101.5,
    "repliesPerDay": 1.3333333333333333,
    "customersHelped": 16,
    "totalConversations": 42,
    "conversationsPerDay": 0.4
  },
  "deltas": {
    "totalConversations": -54.761904761904766,
    "customersHelped": 62.5,
    "happinessScore": 43.13725490196077,
    "repliesPerDay": 45.000000000000014,
    "resolvedOnFirstReply": -100.0,
    "handleTime": 0.0,
    "conversationsPerDay": 58.33333333333333,
    "resolved": -91.66666666666666,
    "repliesToResolve": -7.692307692307687,
    "activeConversations": -54.761904761904766,
    "totalReplies": 44.99999999999999,
    "closed": -90.9090909090909,
    "responseTime": -3.3584779029420475,
    "resolutionTime": -47.245241919394445,
    "conversationsCreated": 650.0
  }
}
```

JSON I get back from API:

```
"{\"filterTags\":[{\"name\":\"general questions\",\"id\":295508},{\"name\":\"request/suggestion\",\"id\":372291},{\"name\":\"support.dd.com incorrect\",\"id\":547376},{\"name\":\"status update\",\"id\":295502},{\"name\":\"support.dd.com other\",\"id\":547378},{\"name\":\"promos/gift cards\",\"id\":295547}],\"user\":{\"createdAt\":\"2015-05-04T16:32:21Z\",\"photoUrl\":\"https://d33v4339jhl8k0.cloudfront.net/users/99999.23342.jpg\",\"hasPhoto\":true,\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"totalCustomersHelped\":261,\"id\":99999},\"current\":{\"startDate\":\"2015-08-15T12:00:00Z\",\"endDate\":\"2015-08-16T18:00:00Z\",\"totalDays\":1,\"resolved\":4,\"conversationsCreated\":0,\"closed\":11,\"totalReplies\":5,\"resolvedOnFirstReply\":3,\"percentResolvedOnFirstReply\":60.0,\"repliesToResolve\":1.25,\"handleTime\":346.6,\"happinessScore\":0.0,\"responseTime\":3467,\"resolutionTime\":4704.25,\"repliesPerDay\":5.0,\"customersHelped\":4,\"totalConversations\":12,\"conversationsPerDay\":12.0,\"busiestDay\":6}}"
```

My Classes:

```
public class User
{
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool HasPhoto { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TotalCustomersHelped { get; set; }
    public string PhotoURL { get; set; }
}

public class TimeRangeStats
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public int TotalDays { get; set; }
    public int Resolved { get; set; }
    public int ConversationsCreated { get; set; }
    public int Closed { get; set; }
    public int TotalReplies { get; set; }
    public int ResolvedOnFirstReply { get; set; }
    public double PercentResolvedOnFirstReply { get; set; }
    public double RepliesToResolve { get; set; }
    public double HandleTime { get; set; }
    public double HappinessScore { get; set; }
    public double ResponseTime { get; set; }
    public double ResolutionTime { get; set; }
    public double RepliesPerDay { get; set; }
    public int CustomersHelped { get; set; }
    public int TotalConversations { get; set; }
    public double ConversationsPerDay { get; set; }
    public int BusiestDay { get; set; }
}

public class MultipleTimeRangeStats
{
    public double TotalConversations { get; set; }
    public double CustomersHelped { get; set; }
    public double HappinessScore { get; set; }
    public double RepliesPerDay { get; set; }
    public double ResolvedOnFirstReply { get; set; }
    public double HandleTime { get; set; }
    public double ConversationsPerDay { get; set; }
    public double Resolved { get; set; }
    public double RepliesToResolve { get; set; }
    public double ActiveConversations { get; set; }
    public double TotalReplies { get; set; }
    public double Closed { get; set; }
    public double ResponseTime { get; set; }
    public double ResolutionTime { get; set; }
    public double ConversationsCreated { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
}

public class UserReport
{
    public List<Tag> FilterTags { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public TimeRangeStats Current { get; set; }
    public TimeRangeStats Previous { get; set; }
    public MultipleTimeRangeStats Deltas { get; set; }
}
```

Serializer Settings:

```
private JsonSerializerSettings _serializerSettings
        {
            get
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
                    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,                    
                };
                serializer.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter {CamelCaseText = true});

                return serializer;
            }
        }
```

I hope this is not an overwhelming amount of information to ask about.

HelpScoutNet: https://github.com/Selz/HelpScoutNet

Relevant HelpScout API: http://developer.helpscout.net/help-desk-api/reports/user/user/

Edit: Got the tracer to work, get this result. Which is thoroughly confusing that it can't find those properties yet it works on other classes that as far as I can tell are built the same:

```
2015-08-18T00:59:30.188 Info Started deserializing HelpScoutNet.SingleItem`1[Hel
pScoutNet.Model.Report.User.UserReports.UserReport]. Path 'filterTags', line 1,
position 14.
2015-08-18T00:59:30.189 Verbose Could not find member 'filterTags' on HelpScoutN
et.SingleItem`1[HelpScoutNet.Model.Report.User.UserReports.UserReport]. Path 'fi
lterTags', line 1, position 14.
2015-08-18T00:59:30.194 Verbose Could not find member 'user' on HelpScoutNet.Sin
gleItem`1[HelpScoutNet.Model.Report.User.UserReports.UserReport]. Path 'user', l
ine 1, position 276.
2015-08-18T00:59:30.198 Verbose Could not find member 'current' on HelpScoutNet.
SingleItem`1[HelpScoutNet.Model.Report.User.UserReports.UserReport]. Path 'curre
nt', line 1, position 470.
2015-08-18T00:59:30.200 Info Finished deserializing HelpScoutNet.SingleItem`1[He
lpScoutNet.Model.Report.User.UserReports.UserReport]. Path '', line 1, position
896.
```

Comment: The JSON in your question corresponds to a `UserReport` not a [`SingleItem<UserReport>`](https://github.com/Selz/HelpScoutNet/blob/21f044d87af24e86110d90faaea860a384ad783f/src/HelpScoutClient.cs) -- there's no outer `{"item": ...}` container object.  How are you trying to deserialize it?

Comment: Oh wow. I must be completely blind to have missed that. Please post this as an answer, I will happily mark it as correct, that was the issue. Totally flying by the seat of my pants on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON in your question corresponds to your `UserReport` class, not a [`SingleItem<UserReport>`](https://github.com/Selz/HelpScoutNet/blob/21f044d87af24e86110d90faaea860a384ad783f/src/HelpScoutClient.cs) -- there's no outer `{"item": ...}` container object.  So you need to deserialize it as such.